# Wedding anniversaries with org-contacts

Tags: org-mode

I successfully managed to add birthdays with [org-contacts](https://julien.danjou.info/projects/emacs-packages#org-contacts) using the `:BIRTHDAY:` property, but what about some other kind of anniversaries such as wedding anniversaries? How can I set them? Can I use the `:WEDDING:` property for example?

Comment: That's the nice thing about org property drawers.  You can put nearly anything in them.  With respect to org-contacts.el: the anniversary(birthday) logic would need to be refactored to support generalized (i.e. labeled) anniversaries like describe.  FWIW: using `:WEDDING:` properties is be exactly where I would start :-)